# Find the Frictional Component of the Contact Force.

Tags: classical-mechanics

[This question is about Mechanics. I wonder what precisely are Normal Components and Frictional Components of Contact Force](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZLKc.jpg)

Comment: There is a specified stack exchange forum for physics, plus in any question you ask, you need to at least show some effort.

Comment: I think u sought for Physics.SE?

Comment: where can i find that section ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Frictional component acts along the plane. Normal Component acts at the perpendicular of the plane. Good enough?

Comment: the answer says like this.... -mgsin(21)-F = -5m where we already know -5 is accelaration. But the question is that mgsin(21) is already the Frictional Component so what is F there ?

Comment: Simply, Contact force is the net force offered by plane to the object. These normal and frictional components are just their It's perpendicular components @AlperenBulgur

Comment: so what about that extra F ?

Comment: What extra F? F simply denotes frictional component. @AlperenBulgur

Comment: then what exactly is mgsin(21) ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole question? @AlperenBulgur

Comment: yes exactly...i dont understand which one is the frictional force...mgsin(21) or F....in any case what exactly is the second variable ?

Comment: NOTE: $mg \sin 21^o -ma=F$ where $a=5 ms^{-2}$ @AlperenBulgur